# Mega Menu Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, megamenu

I have a mega menu I've been having two issues with.

1. I can't seem to keep the hover state active when I'm hovering over each section.
2. The header tags that trigger the mega menu seem to have a width of the container that they are in. This causes the mega menu to pop up even if you don't rollover it visually.

I posted my current code for the mega menu here: http://www.boyga.com/mega-menu/

I'm using the hoverintent plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue #2 is easy to fix. Add this CSS rule to your stylesheet:

```
ul#Top-Nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Issue #1 is almost as simple. It's more CSS changes. Because your submenu descents from the `<li`> but not the `<a>`, you need to change your CSS rules that involve `a:hover` and `a:active`:

```
    ul#Top-Nav li:hover a{color:#1E90FF;text-decoration:none;}
    ul#Top-Nav li:hover a{background:#1E90FF url(arrow.png) no-repeat right center;color:#fff;}
    ul#Top-Nav li:active a{background:#1E90FF url(arrow.png) no-repeat right center;color:#fff;}
```

This works for me, at least on Chrome. You may (read: probably) will have issues on other browsers, where the `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes don't bubble up.